# What formula we have to use for fit_transform method?

Tags: python, machine-learning, methods, scikit-learn, transform

What formula we have to use to get these numbers in print(X_train)?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MwLN.png)

Comment: I know that we use sklearn library for that, but I would like to know how exactly it's calculating by the formula

Answer (score 0):

That's how Standardscaler function calculates:

[image]

If you want to dig deep into it, refer - http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html#standardization-and-min-max-scaling